# PG gem errors on attempting to make connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have installed Postgres 8.4.4 via MacPorts per a RobbyOnRails installation guide.  When I attempt to connect to a project I get the following error:

```
establish_connection':RuntimeError: Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle: mach-o, but wrong architecture - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/pg-0.9.0/lib/pg_ext.bundle)
```

The PG gem successfully installs, but the above error is generated.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you run `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter`?

Comment: That gem doesn't exist/ isn't supported anymore

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the PG gem was not being uninstalled from all locations.  Once I forced the uninstall paths, everything seemed to work.